# Do bounties count toward daily reputation cap?

Tags: support, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

Suppose I just earned +500 bounty on a question (I did); am I done for the day (for non-bounty rep), or does bounty-derived rep not count toward the 200 daily maximum?

Comment: You can hunt has much as you want and collect them. It will be counter productive if it was in the 200 daily cap.

Answer (score -10, accepted):

No, they don't - verified this myself: after earning +500 from a bounty, you can continue earning rep from upvotes, accepted answers, etc, up to the 200 daily cap.

Other answers and the official guide uses unclear wording, hence figured it worth answering explicitly.

Answer (score 4):

Per https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty

> As a special bonus, any reputation you earn from being awarded a bounty is exempt from the daily reputation cap.

Comment: I've read all the answers, but the wording isn't very clear; to clarify, the +500 will _not_ count toward the 200 daily cap, and I can continue earning rep from upvotes?

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon that's true.

Comment: that's what exempt means.

Comment: @RobertLongson It was unclear whether "exempt" was referring to "if you get 500 from bounty it'll be 500 not 200", which I already knew; either way I'll be able to verify for sure myself sometime today